Adding two timelines
I would like to add a second timeline (instead of facet) to a barplot.
I tried to group by two vars but this is not working as expected (I get a mixed timeline).
Are there any smart workarounds?
A sample code:
mtcars |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |>
  mutate(total = mpg + qsec) |>
  group_by(cyl,gear) |>
  arrange(desc(total)) |>
  e_charts(model,timeline = TRUE) |>
  e_bar(mpg, stack = "grp") |>
  e_bar(qsec, stack = "grp") %>% 
  e_legend(selectedMode = "single")


I don't think echarts4r supports two timelines.

@yuk, are you aware of any approaches that do support two timelines?
